# dotnet run - looking for Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 (not preview) - I never refer to it

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

I have a fairly in-depth project setup with 10-20 libraries, and I'm trying to build an executable which uses them.

I have .NET Core 1.1.0 preview1 installed.  With new projects, everything works fine.  `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` also work fine for this project, but somewhere along the line, something is wrong, and it will not run.

`dotnet run` yields:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.0.1
      1.1.0-preview1-001100-00
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.0'.
```

My library projects have:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1-preview1-*"
      }
    }
  }
```

My executable project has:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.1.0-preview1-*",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      },
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  }
```

It does also reference another project which is set up with an entry point, whose `frameworks` section is identical, minus the `imports` section.

I've also updated any EF Core and ASP.NET Core references to their `preview1-*` versions, though I am using plenty of other dependencies too (which weren't versioned in the same way).

So, as you can see, I have `1.1.0-preview1-001100-00` installed, am not referencing `1.1.0` anywhere, and yet receiving this message looking for it.

What could be causing this, and/or how can I track it down?  I've tried scouring `project.json.lock` files, but can't see any references to 1.1.0 there, with the exception of an entry for `Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0` under `libraries` and again under the `".NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1"` part of `targets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards aren't appropriate and don't work for this kind of platform dependency.

It's necessary to use

`"version": "1.1.0-preview1-001100-00"`

and not

`"version": "1.1.0-preview1-*"`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with the same problem deploying on Heroku instance. In may case during deployment the latest build is used (https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/linux-x64-46_binding.node).

As a workaround it works if change

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview1-*",
```

to

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
```

but on the other hand, it stops to work on local machine in this case...